# What happens if I let the train explode in Chapter 2 Act 4?

Tags: a-hat-in-time

In Chapter 2: Act 4 of A Hat in Time, the Conductor threatens to blow up his train so he can get action footage for his new movie. He says that you need to reach the front of the train in under 2 minutes to defuse the bomb.

What happens if you sit and let the timer run out? Does the train actually explode?

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't try it out yourself?

Comment: Delays probably, and the use of buses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Disappointingly, the train will not explode if the timer runs out.**

I ended up testing this out myself. I pulled the train’s self-destruct switch and waited two minutes for the countdown to run out.

When the timer hits 0, Hat Kid loses all her health and dies, as if hit by an enemy. The counter is reset back to two minutes, and you respawn at the start of the level.